# JNI: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries, when I install my application on different PC

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am developing a JAVA plugin that uses JNI to call another C++ code.
On my PC every thing is working fine, when I tried to install the plugin on different PC I had this exception "Can't find dependent libraries". By testing what is the problem it seems that the plugin is not able to load the "jansi -64.dll" library. 
Knowing that the JNILib.dll (which was developed by us) is in a path which is in the PATH environment variable.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check if there are any other files required by jansi -64.dll which were present on you PC.

Comment: Make sure you are using the 64-bit JVM. A 32-bit JVM will complain it cannot find a compatible DLL even though an incompatible one is available.

Comment: How to check? @Harinder. In fact the plugin is for Cytoscape software and when I run Maven install in eclipse to build my code the "jansi 64.dll " library is generated. I tried to copy the one which was generated on my PC to the new PC but that did not work.